# Existence of solution of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$ a function such that $f(1)=0$ and let $0 < x_0 < 1$. Prove that the Cauchy problem
$\begin{cases} x'=xf(x^2+y^2)-y \\ y'=yf(x^2+y^2)+x \\ x(0) = x_0 \\ y(0) = 0 \end{cases}$

Has a solution, and it is defined in $\mathbb{R}$.

So I know I can write the problem as
$\begin{cases} z'=A(t)z \\ z(0) = (x_0, 0) \end{cases}$

Where $z = (x, y)$ and $A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} f(x^2+y^2) & -1 \\ 1 & f(x^2+y^2) \end{pmatrix}$

And since $t \mapsto A(t)$ is continuous map then the Cauchy problem has a solution, globally defined (I've seen this problem: the function $(t,z) \mapsto A(t)z$ is locally Lipschitz and sublinear). My proof is probably wrong since I don't use the hypothesis $f(1)=0$ and $0<x_0<1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac 12\left(\ln(x^2+y^2)\right)' = f(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: I think also that the two assumptions are not necessary for the existence of a solution. Another proof is to denote $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$ then the system of equations is equivalent to $\theta' = 1$ and $r' = r f(r^2)$. We deduce then $\theta = t +\text{const}$. For $r$, it's easy to prove that its equation is locally Lipschitz and so has solution for every initial condition.

Comment: Working in polar coordinates, as suggested by NN2, you can use the hypotheses $f(1)=0$ and $0<x_0<1$ to show that the solution is confined to the disk $r<1$, therefore is defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (no blow-up).